# Simple select query running slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have about 1000 entries in table. It's simple table with 10 columns. Query:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

server runs the query, but is processing it for a long time.

P.S. I know this is not enough info, so please comment and I will add what is needed.

Comment: Are you sure it's the server that get's stuck?

Comment: Have you really only got 1000 entries in that table? What does SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table return?

Comment: What is the problem with your query? Can you provide input data and expected result?

Comment: What does "gets stuck" even mean?? SQL Server can handle terabytes of data. Unless you provide more info it's impossible to help. Perhaps the table has more data than you thought, or the way you call the query blocks client-side. Perhaps you are trying some *other* query at the same time that causes blocking.

Comment: What do you mean by 'get server stuck'. The whole server stops working or is it just the query editor window?

Comment: Are you sure it's a (base) table and not a view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Not related to SQL. Server got overflown by data. Someone was spamming it.

Comment: Good (or bad) to hear.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use TOP. For example try to select 100 rows and look if server still stucks:

```
SELECT TOP 100 * FROM my_table
```

Comment: Tried that, but as I said, not so much entries. If I use top 1 it gets listed after 20 seconds, if I use "top 100" it gets stuck again.

Comment: Seems to be problem with your server.